# $\{X_n\}_{n=1}^\infty \sim\mathcal{U}[0,1]$ are independence random variables, $f$ continuous in $[0,1]$.

Tags: probability

$\{X_n\}_{n=1}^\infty \sim\mathcal{U}[0,1]$ are independence random variables, $f$ continuous in $[0,1]$.

Prove $P\left(\left|\frac{1}{N}\sum_{n=1}^Nf(X_n) - \int_0^1f(t)dt\right| >\epsilon\right)\to 0$ when $N \to \infty$

I try to solve this using the "Weak Law of Large Numbers."

I get why it is common sense, but have no idea how to prove it.

Any help please ?

Comment: Do you know that $\int_0^1 f(t)\,dt=E(f(X_i))?$ If $Y_i=f(X_i)$ then you have $Y_i=f(X_i),$ do you know that the $Y_i$ are independent, identical r.v.?

Comment: I got it! I ignored the fact that $f_{x{_i}}=1$ , thanks !